# Putting a texfield inside a table using Handlebars

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am new at using Handlebars, and I have simple question. I am trying to create table that contains a title and a text field next to it. When I try to place the textfields in the table, the textfields is placed on top of the table instead.

This is the code that I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Handlebars.js example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="placeholder">This will get replaced by handlebars.js</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
    <script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <table>
        {{#each names}}
            <tr><th>{{name}}</th><input type="text"></tr>
        {{/each}}
        </table>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var source = document.getElementById("myTemplate").innerHTML;
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var data = {
            names: [
            { name: "foo",id:'id'},
            { name: "bar",id:'id' },
            { name: "baz",id:'id' }
            ]};
              document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = template(data);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table structure is bad.  You're missing a tbody and your input is in a row, but not in a th or td.

Comment: putting in a tbody didn't help. But putting the input into td did. Thanks!